# angularjs expand all accordion inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting data from a service, so the number of accordions will be variable. I used ng-repeat to dynamically display the accordion

```
<div ng-controller = "groupController">

<div ng-repeat = "groups in groupNames">
    <div class = "panel-group" id = "accordion">
    <div class = "panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class = "panel-title">
            <a data-toggle= "collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{$index}}"> {{groups.team}} </a>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse{{$index}}" class = "panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class = "panel-body">
            <!-- display some data in the panel body -->
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </div>
</div>

<button class = "btn btn-primary">collapseAll</button>
<button class = "btn btn-primary">expandAll</button>

</div>
```

How do I achieve collapse all and expand all using the controller. The answers that I found mainly solved the accordion provided by ui-bootstrap. In particular how do I manipulate the hrefs in angularjs to get collapse all and expand all?

Answer (score 1):

At first you should remember to set `close-others=false` for your `accordion`, because in `ui-bootstrap` it is `close-others=true` by default which means that you can only expand one group at a time.

Then you can control the `is-open` property of the `accordion-group` by binding it to some variable in your controller. And then link the buttons to some function in your controller that set all these variables to be `true` or `false`.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DjLm43vKuoVLHHJbizvq?p=preview) is an example on Plunker.

Comment: I did it using ui-bootstrap's accordion..... I wanted to know how to deal with this problem if its not a ui-bootsrtap's accordion. I want to manipulate it using href attribute